# Does Islam support reincarnation?

Tags: islamic-basis

Salam,
      Does Islam support reincarnation? What is your take based on Quran and hadith? Some people based on Quran and hadith argue that Islam supports reincarnation. But it seems to me this subject is complicated. Thanks you for your honest opinions and insights.

Comment: You can see [this link](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa736) in order to be familiar with Islam's viewpoint regarding Reincarnation.

Answer (score -1):

In the name of God, the Most Merciful, Most Kind.

**Answer:**

**In the name of God, We praise Him, seek His help and ask for His forgiveness. Whoever God guides none can misguide, and whoever He allows to fall astray, none can guide them aright. We bear witness that there is none worthy of worship but God Alone, and we bear witness that Muhammad (saws) is His slave-servant and the seal of His Messengers.**

No, dear brother, Islam does not support reincarnation at all, because, it is a Hinduism thing, because God Almighty Says:

> “Everyone shall taste death. Then unto Us you shall be returned”[ al-‘Ankaboot 29:57 ]
>
> How can you disbelieve in God when you were lifeless and He brought you to life; then He will cause you to die, then He will bring you [back] to life, and then to Him you will be returned.[2:28]

This verse means that, if you were for example at the “Era of Prophets” and you were to die at a certain age, you may have been granted second chance, to live, and do good, but if you born in the “Modern Era” and you do bad for example, then you would never ever be raised except when the Day of Resurrection comes, then you’ll be awaked by God, because God has closed permanent the “Era of Prophets”. And God Says:

> “And the Trumpet will be blown (i.e. the second blowing) and behold! From the graves they will come out quickly to their Lord.” (Quran 36:51)

This means, everyone will be awaked, including you on the Day of Resurrection.

The dead disbeliever and I think a dead sinner believer will say:

> [For such is the state of the disbelievers], until, when death comes to one of them, he says, "My Lord, send me back  [23:99]
>
> [23:100] That I might do righteousness in that which I left behind." No! It is only a word he is saying; and behind them is a barrier until the Day they are resurrected.

God Almighty Says:

> ”I will cast terror into the hearts of those who disbelieve. Therefore strike off their heads”

Ibn ‘Abbaas said:

> ”Whoever rejects what God has revealed is a disbeliever.” [al-Maa’idah 5:44]
>
> ”Surely those who disbelieve and die as disbelievers are condemned by God, the angels, and all of humanity”

So, from these verses we learn that if someone disbelieve in what God tells you(e.g. don’t believe in reincarnation and you do believe in it) that is a disbelief, because it is not true.

The one who believes in reincarnation, has indeed committed a disbelief. Because when God has said, no, it means, no, no more going back to life only on the Day of Resurrection, and that Day, everyone will be announced of what he or she did on Earth and one of them will be Punished or Rewarded on that Day. Because God Almighty Says:

> ”Verily, He knows each one of them, and has counted them a full counting.
>
> And everyone of them will come to Him alone on the Day of Resurrection (without any helper, or protector or defender)” [ Maryam 19:94-95 ]

And God Almighty also Says:

> “To Him is the return of all of you. The Promise of God is true. It is He Who begins the creation and then will repeat it, that He may reward with justice those who believed and did deeds of righteousness. But those who disbelieved will have a drink of boiling fluids and painful torment because they used to disbelieve” [ Yunus 10:4 ]

So, in other words, there is no such thing “reincarnation”

And God Almighty also Says:

> And surely you will come to Us alone in the same manner as We created you at the first time, and you have left behind all that We bestowed upon you and…surely We shall cut off all your attachments.

It says in Fataawa al-Lajnah ad-Daa’imah:

> ”The one who denies that we should follow the Sunnah is a disbeliever, because he is expressing disbelief in God and His Messenger, and rejecting the consensus of the Muslim”.

This means including the verses, if you disbelief the verses from Quran, you have committed a disbelief.

And God also Says:

> How can you reject faith in God? Do you not recall that you were once without life, and God gave you life; then God will cause you to die, and will again bring you to life; and finally to God will you return.[surah, 2:28]

This means that He created and brought you to life, and He will be the one who will take you back to Him one day, and He will bring you back to life on the Day of Resurrection, to stand on the land of Judgment, so that He will tell you the results on the test you made, that’s it. And life is only a test and if you die, finish, you will never be brought again nor converted into another body but to wait till the Last Day and face the Day of Judgment and finish, there’s no reincarnation.

God says (interpretation of the meaning):

> ”And He it is Who has created the heavens and the earth in six Days and His Throne was on the water, that He might try you, which of you is the best in deeds. But if you were to say to them: “You shall indeed be raised up after death,” those who disbelieve would be sure to say, “This is nothing but obvious magic”
>
> [Hood 11:7]

And God Almighty also Says:

> “Who has created death and life that He may test you which of you is best in deed. And He is the AllMighty, the OftForgiving”
>
> [al-Mulk 67:2]

So from these verses we learn that this life is only a test, but if one of us died for example, in state of disbelief then finish, no more going back to worldly life, never ever.

And you have to understand that, it is a disbelief, period, to believe in reincarnation.

Because whoever told you that reincarnation is “true” in reality it is not true. And if you believe in reincarnation, God Almighty Says:

> ”Surely, those who disbelieved in Our Ayaat (proofs, evidences, verses, lessons, signs, revelations, etc.), We shall burn them in Fire. As often as their skins are roasted through, We shall change them for other skins that they may taste the punishment”
>
> Except the way of Hell, to dwell therein forever”[al-Jaathiyah, 45:35]

Because, reincarnation, simply does not exist , it is only something unrealistic. Those who claim that “reincarnation” exists, well they do claim like this because of this lack of knowledge. Remember this:

> ”Believe none of what you hear and half of what you see” - Benjamin Franklin.

This means, what you need to believe only what God tells you, if God tells you that reincarnation does not exist, finish, you don’t argue with God, because that what He decided not to exist reincarnation. And you have to believe only what God Almighty tells you. Do you believe that ghosts exist? Of course not, because, it is something that does not exist. And it is something that God already said that when someone dies, then will remain in grave till the Day of Judgment to see the results of what that person did. And if He were to tell you that reincarnation exist, then you can believe in it, but as long as He wanted that reincarnation not exist, then you have to believe and obey what God ordered you to do.

And a hadith on this matter from Alī ibn Mūsā al-Riḍā:

> ”Someone who believes in Reincarnation is a disbeliever and has refuted heaven and hell.”

prophet Muhammad( peace and blessings of God be upon him) said:

> “In man there is a bone which will not be consumed by the earth, and from it he will be regenerated on the Day of Resurrection.” They asked, “What bone is that, O Messenger of God?” He said, “The tailbone.” (Narrated by Muslim, 5255).”

God Says (interpretation of the meaning):

> ”To Him is the return of all of you. The Promise of God is true. It is He Who begins the creation and then will repeat it, that He may reward with justice those who believed and did deeds of righteousness. But those who disbelieved will have a drink of boiling fluids and painful torment because they used to disbelieve” [ Yunus 10:4 ]

But that doesn’t mean that reincarnation exist. No, it does not exist, here it means that you will remain dead till the Day of Resurrection when God will wake you up to stand on the land of Judgment.

God Says:

> Verily, He knows each one of them, and has counted them a full counting.
>
> And everyone of them will come to Him alone on the Day of Resurrection (without any helper, or protector or defender)” [ Maryam 19:94-95 ]

And God Says:

> ”Allaah! Laa ilaaha illa Huwa (none has the right to be worshipped but He). Surely, He will gather you together on the Day of Resurrection about which there is no doubt” [ al-Nisa’ 4:87 ]

So, no, dear brother, Islam does not support reincarnation at all.

**Whatever written of Truth and benefit is only due to God’s Assistance and Guidance, and whatever of error is of me alone. God Alone Knows Best and He is the Only Source of Strength.**

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate.

Comment: @goldPseudo What?? I did not argumented, I just need a reason to why it was downvoted because, maybe I have done something wrong and I do not know.